# How to print the entire python idle commands history to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-idle

How to print the entire python idle commands history to a text file. For example the list of commands I already typed

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can. There is no access to the idle app from the interpreter, if you could get access then `pyshell.history` is where the history is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One prints the contents of a Shell window the same as an editor or output window.  Select `File` and then `Print Window` and then `OK`.  Or use the shortcut key, which on Windows, at least, is Control-P.  I verified that this works on Windows with 2.7.13 and 3.6.1.

One can also save Shell content with `File`, `Save As` and then edit the result.  Then print if one wants a paper copy.

https://bugs.python.org/issue11838 is about making it easier to get running code from a shell log.  One problem with saving just the user input is that it loses the bug information in tracebacks.